# Is there a way to make the destinations in a BottomNavigationView appear evenly distributed across its length in landscape mode

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, material-components-android

[image: Bottom navigation view equally spaced items]

It would be even better if the text appears below the respective icon while the icons are evenly distributed.
Currently, the items appear stacked in landscape mode.

Current implementation:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_bar"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView.Colored"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/selector_icon_tint_bottom_nav"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/selector_icon_tint_bottom_nav"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav" />
```

Comment: It would be nice if you show some code of what you are doing

Answer (score 0):

Try this out I hope it will work.Its working for me

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
      android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom"
      android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
      app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled" 
      app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
      app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
      app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Make a menu directory under res and in that directory make an XML layout

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:title="Home" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile"
        android:title="Profile" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_about"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_aboutUs"
        android:title="About Us" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_logout"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_logout"
        android:title="Logout" />

</menu>
```

In main activity implement BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener and implements its all method then you can do your desire action on each icon

```
 bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_view);

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

}
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.navigation_home:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Home", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();           
            return true;

        case R.id.navigation_profile:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Profile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.navigation_about:
            Toast.makeText(this, "About Us", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.navigation_logout:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Logout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

    }

    return false;
}
```

Edited :For video tutorial you can also see this tutorial
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oeKtwd1DBfg)

Comment: Priority is making the destination equally spaced. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: please show the code of you bottom navigation 
(in the image they already look like equally aligned)

Comment: The goal is to make a bottom nav like the image but with text appearing below the icons while the icons being equally spaced.

Comment: Ok 
Iam updating the answer

Comment: I don't understand, you've just added a background color, gravity and wrapped it inside a Framelayout, how is this going to help?

Comment: Its working perfectly fine for me.The image you have uploaded that also looked align and if you want I can post code for menu and for action on menu selection

Comment: Did you got your solution